# knockout js calling a property from outside the view model always null

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to implement `BlueImp` file upload functionality and pass the uploaded urls to my knockout viewmodel.

My problem is that when I try and select the required item from the property, that property is always null, why?

I have added my code below:

```
<script>
var viewModel = null;
var $form = null;

$(function () {
    var jsonData = someSerilizedDataFromTheServer;
    viewModel = new ViewModel(@Html.Raw(jsonData))
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $form = $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json'
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        // here this is called for each individual file
        if (typeof data.result != 'undefined') {
            debugger;

            var file = data.result.files[0]
            var roomId = $("#hdnRoomId").val();
            viewModel.addImageUrl(roomId, file.url);
        }
    });
});
$('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
</script>
```

koViewModel.js

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
var self = this;

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

..other stuff

this.addRoom = function() {
    self.Rooms.push(new Room());
}

this.addImageUrl = function(roomId, imageUrl) {
    debugger;

    var room = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Rooms(), function(roomId) {
        return room.RoomID === roomId;
    })
}
..other stuff

}

var Room = function () {
    ..roomProperties
}
```

my html button I add a room with

```
<button id="newRoom" type="button" data-bind="click: addRoom">New Room</button>
```

When debugging it shows self.Rooms() is not a function or self.Rooms undefined. But I have just added a room (the room was added by clicking the above button) so i would expect to see a value

Comment: So where are you assigning `Rooms` a value?

Comment: Is addRoom where you're getting the error? That's the only place I see Rooms being used. What does your view model json look like?

Comment: When the newRoom button is clicked addRoom is called. A new room is shown on the UI, i can then upload images, once the image upload is complete 'fileuploaddone' is called. As you can see this calls addImageUrl and the error occurs in   ko.utils.arrayFirst      So rooms has a been initialized at the point when newRoom button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the Rooms observable array before that?

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
var self = this;

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
self.Rooms = ko.observableArray(); // --> Here?

..other stuff

this.addRoom = function() {
  self.Rooms.push(new Room());
}
```

Because from your error message "self.Rooms() is not a function or self.Rooms undefined." it appears to me that it has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't complaining that Rooms is undefined. It's complaining that "room" is undefined. The error is that your variable names don't match. You've told it that each item in the Rooms array gets passed into the anonymous function as "roomId", and then you try to access "room" which is undefined.

```
var room = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Rooms(), function(roomId) {
    return room.RoomID === roomId;
})
```

"function(**roomId**)" should be "function(**room**)"

```
var room = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Rooms(), function(room) {
    return room.RoomID === roomId;
})
```

You have another "room" variable outside of the function to hold the result though so you might want to rename both of the arrayFirst room variables to something else.